# The equation $(x^2-4)^2 + (y^2-9)^2 = 0$ represents points:

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

> The equation $(x^2-4)^2 + (y^2-9)^2 = 0$ represents points:
>
> $a$. Which lie on the circle with centre at $(0,0)$.
>
> $b$. which lie on a circle with centre $(2,3)$
>
> $c$. Which are collinear
>
> $d$. None of the above.

My Attempt:

The book's answer option $a$ but I don't understand how.

Comment: How is "My attempt" an attempt at all?

Comment: Collinear means [three or more points lie on a straight line](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html). General equation of a circle is $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^=r^2$$ [where $(h,k)$ is the centre of the circle and $r$ is the radius](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/circle/equation-of-a-circle.php). Can you see which is the answer now?

Answer (score 3):

Square of any real quantity is $\geq 0$. So if sum of two squares is $=0$, it means the two squares themselves have to be zero, because if one of them is non-zero, the sum would be greater than zero. Therefore $x^2=4$ and $y^2=9$ which means the points are $(\pm 2,\pm3)$, which lie on a circle centered at $0$ (the circle $x^2+y^2=13$).

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:-**

> $$a^2\ge0\qquad(\text{where $a\in \Bbb{R}$})$$

$$$$

> And what case of this inequality do you have?